# Let $S_4$ be the set of all permutations on $4$ symbols

Tags: permutations

Let $S_4$ be the set of all permutations on $4$ symbols and $A$ a subset of $S_4$ such that 
$$A = \{f\in S_4 : f \text{ is a 3-cycle}\},$$ 
then   $|A|= \mathord{?}$

---

*(included from comments)*
I think number of $3$-cycles of $S_4$ is ${}^4C_3 \times 2 =8$ so order of $A$ is $8$

...since $4 <3+3$ there are $8\ \ 3$-cycles because there are ${}^4C_3$ ways to select the $3$ elements and $2$ times to orient each cycle

...is it correct?

Comment: i think number of 3 cycle of S4 is 4C3 X 2 =8 so order of A is 8 ..is it correct

Comment: Yes, it is correct.  Are you able to explain why it is correct?  Why $\binom{4}{3}$?  Why $2$?  Why multiply them?

Comment: You should include the information that you commented in the body of your question. People on this site like to see that you have attempted the problem yourself.

Comment: It should be $P(4,3)/3=8$, since each $3$ cycle has three different but equivalent forms (e.g., $(123)=(231)=(312)$).

Comment: It is correct. But could you please explain *why* you thought that (maybe by editing your question)? Sometimes even just explaining is helpful to verifying your thinking!

Comment: @zuriel notice that $P(4,3)/3=\binom{4}{3}\cdot 2 = 8$ is just a different way of writing the same answer

Comment: @JMoravitz， thanks for pointing out. I did not see the OP's reasoning but the answer is correct.

Comment: since 4 <3+3 there are 8  3-cycles because there are 4C3  ways to select the 3 elements and 2 times to orient the cycle.

Comment: Added your thoughts into the question.